# How to get links who follow a pattern within specific section using xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

**Here is what I'm trying to do:**

I have some links on a webpage with this pattern:

- /html/body/div[4]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/**div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PomXI.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PomXI.png)**/div/div[2]/a
- /html/body/div[4]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/**div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PomXI.png)/div[2]**/div/div[2]/a
- /html/body/div[4]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/**div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PomXI.png)/div[3]**/div/div[2]/a
- /html/body/div[4]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/**div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PomXI.png)/div[4]**/div/div[2]/a

However, I also have **other links** within the same web page that have a similar path but not exactly following the same pattern:

/html/body/div[4]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]**/div/div[3]**/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PomXI.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PomXI.png)/div/div[2]/a

**How can I get just the links which follow the first pattern displayed and ignore the other ones?**

Ps: I'm using Selenium Webdriver and Java and this is the update question with the html for the links

```
 <div class="col-sm-6 half-tile">
        <div class="outside-caro">
            <div class="grey-overlay">
                <div class="inside-caro" style="background-image:url(' https://resources/images/metabolism.jpg'")>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile-content">
                <h4 class="module title-long-card">Healthy Weight Loss</h4>
                <p class="module line-clamp">This online eLearning programme is designed to help you make smart decisions when it comes to dieting and to be aware of the pitfalls.</p>
                <a class="more-button" href="/application/res-courses/overview?id=23">Learn More<i style="font-size: 10px;padding-left: 5px; "class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Thanks very much.

Comment: [No noises in question please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Could you provide the HTML code of the links?

Comment: Hi @Anand. I've updated my question with the HTML for the links that I'm trying to target. Thank you. :)

Comment: Can you share a link to the page or at least an example page? Are you looking to always click the "Learn More" link? In general, XPaths that are that long and/or start from html are brittle... they will break with any tiny change in the DOM. The better way is to handcraft a locator that targets what you want.

Comment: Hi @JeffC, sorry I can't share a link to the page as it's password protected. Basically, I don't actually need to click those links. I just need to check if the links I have stored on my array and which have been retrieved from another page are the very ones that this new page shows but just the ones under a specific section, as below that all the available links are shown anyways. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 WebElement pointer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]"));

// Generic path to simulate the change in the xpath for the elements of the following pattern:
// WebElement tag1 = pointer.findElement(By.xpath("./div[1]/div/div[2]/a"));
// WebElement tag2 = pointer.findElement(By.xpath("./div[2]/div/div[2]/a"));

List<WebElement> linksList = pointer.findElements(By.xpath("./div/div/div[2]/a")); 
    for (WebElement link : linksList) {
        System.out.println(link.getAttribute("href"));
    }
```

Comment: Answer that solved the problem according to @MivaScott's suggestion

Answer (score 1):

*I'm not quite following what you're really hoping for from your description, but I can make some guesses.*

The quick answer is, ***just always give the full path***.

But there are ways to make things a little easier to code. There are a couple ways you can create a *pointer* on the page and to only look for things beyond that point. The most straightforward is using simple string concatenation:

```
String pointer = "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]";
WebElement tag1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(pointer + "/div[1]/div/div[2]/a"));
WebElement tag2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(pointer + "/div[2]/div/div[2]/a"));
```

The other is to declare that pointer as a WebElement, and then use it as a base for all future findElements:

```
WebElement pointer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]"));
WebElement tag1 = pointer.findElement(By.xpath("./div[1]/div/div[2]/a"));
WebElement tag2 = pointer.findElement(By.xpath("./div[2]/div/div[2]/a"));
```

Note the dot at the beginning of the xpath to say "Use this node as your starting point".

Now, what I think you're **really** trying to accomplish to to make a list of all the anchors, not just pick them one by one. As in *"get all the link that match one pattern but not a different but similar pattern"*. For that, you could just do a variation of either of the two above methods. For instance:

```
WebElement pointer = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]"));
List<WebElement> tags = pointer.findElement(By.xpath("./div/div/div[2]/a"));
```

This will pull in all the links that match the pattern into a List. There are a couple things to take note:

- The first element is just `div`, not `div[1]` and `div[2]`. since that seems to be the only thing changing in the pattern.
- Most likely, the language you will use to script this is 0-indexed. So `div[1]` is `tags.get(0)`.

Comment: Hi @MivaScott, Thanks so much for your reply. I've added a picture of the page in case that may help to clarify what I'm trying to achieve? In summary, The user will be recommended a series of courses according to their answers to a questionnaire and I need to check if they're the expected courses which are displayed under that section. The tricky thing is that all the courses are also displayed in the webpage anyways within the All Courses section, so I can't really check if the page contains that course. I mean, I can check if they appear twice but that doesn't seem the best solution for it.

Comment: Hi again @MivaScott. Tried again and using pointers solved the problem. :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: @FrancislainyCampos, I'm glad it worked for you. If you get a chance, can you mark this as the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to problem and i hope it will help you.

You just have to identify a single parent for all 4 links that you mentioned above. And i feel you can use this locator as parent node `/html/body/div[4]/div/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]`.

Please find my code..

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.abodeqa.com/2015/08/26/finding-child-elements-in-webdriver-using-findelements/");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//section[@class='secondary clearfix']"));
    List<WebElement>childernNodes = parent.findElements(By.xpath("./aside//a"));
    System.out.println("Total: "+childernNodes.size());
    for(WebElement value: childernNodes){
       System.out.println(value.getAttribute("href")); 
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Pradeep. Thanks a lot for your reply. I've read the attached blog post a couple of times now and tried to implement their suggestion but haven't been able to make it work yet. I've updated my question with a picture of the layout of the page in case that helps to clarify what I'm trying to achieve? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Pradeep. Thanks for that. I was able to make it work with MivaScott's solution and answered my own question with a shorter version of that just in case someone may come across the same problem they would have a more straight forward solution. I'm sure your solution will be able to help someone else though. :)